# How to stop grunt serve to automatically adding files

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I have used `yo angular` for my project. 
Now I wanted to added bootstrap-sass-official which I did using 
`bower install --save bootstrap-sass-official`

When I run `grunt serve` it automatically adds the javascript files to index.html, which I dont want.

I am using `ui-bootstrap` for modals and other components.

How do I stop grunt serve from adding of additional javascript files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by commenting a part of `bowerInstall` task. 
Now I have to add the files manually but I have the flexibility to decide for myself.
I can still see which files were to be added automatically, from bower.json (search for "main") file inside the `bower_component/component_name` folder.

**Earlier:**

```
bowerInstall: {
            app: {
              src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
              ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
            },
            sass: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/'
            }
}
```

**Now:**

```
bowerInstall: {
            /* app: {
              src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
              ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
            }, */
            sass: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/'
            }
}
```